# Copy every second value of a row and paste into a column in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

pls help, I need a excel vba code, which copies every second value of a row
[image: Sheet1]

and paste that into a column in another sheet

[image: Tabelle1].

I tried it like this

```
Sub Test()

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Dim x As Integer

For x = 5 To 196 Step 2

Worksheets("Tabelle1").Activate

Cells(x, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheets1").Range("E2:GN2")

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim WkSource As Worksheet
Dim WkDestiny As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim LR As Long
Dim k As Long

Set WkSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1")
Set WkDestiny = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja2")

With WkSource
    LR = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 2 'starting row where you want to paste data in destiny sheet
    For i = 2 To LR Step 1
    
        For j = 5 To 12 Step 2 'j=5 to 12 because my data goes from column E to L (5 to 12)
            WkDestiny.Range("D" & k).Value = .Cells(i, j).Value
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End With

Set WkSource = Nothing
Set WkDestiny = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code loop trough each row and each column (notice step 2 to skip columns)

Output I get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Foxfire! This helped me a lot((:

Answer (score 2):

you can start from something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub dataCp()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long, i As Long

Dim rng As Range, c As Range

lcol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For i = 5 To lcol
    lrow = (ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row) + 1
    ws2.Range("D" & lrow).Value = ws.Cells(2, i).Value
    i = i + 1
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Transpose Data

- It will transpose all rows of a range in a worksheet to consecutive columns on another worksheet.
- Since `scStep` is `2`, in this case, only every other cell in each source row will be copied.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TransposeData()
 
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstRowAddress As String = "E2:GN2"
    Const scStep As Long = 2
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Tabelle1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "D2"
    ' Both
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Write the values from the source range to the source array.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sFirstRowAddress)
        ' Populate data.
'        With .Resize(20)
'            .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(1,100)"
'            .Value = .Value
'        End With
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data in data range
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        sData = .Resize(srCount).Value
    End With
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = UBound(sData, 2)
    Dim drCount As Long
    drCount = Int(scCount / scStep) - CLng(scCount Mod scStep > 0)
    
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To srCount)
    
    ' Write the data from the source array to the destination array.
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To srCount
        For r = 1 To drCount
            dData(r, c) = sData(c, (r - 1) * scStep + 1)
        Next r
    Next c
    
    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, srCount) ' first row range
        ' Write data.
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
        ' Apply some formatting.
        '.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data transposed.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```